# Routes priority in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

in my app I have:

```
get '/' do
  # stuff
end
```

with an erb that triggers:

```
post '/' do
  #code
end
```

with an erb that links to /:id that at that moment should trigger

```
get '/:id' do
  #code
end
```

but instead the `get '/:id'` route is always triggered, even when i load the homepage.
I tried to use the pass if but with no happy result. Am I doing something wrong?

In case you want to see the code (I know is terrible):
https://github.com/jackscotti/jobbed/blob/master/jobbed.rb

Comment: Please post some detail on what goes on in these methods and, more importantly, the order in which they have been written.

Comment: https://github.com/jackscotti/jobbed/blob/master/jobbed.rb

Comment: "but instead is always triggered"...? *What* is always triggered? (second from the last paragraph)

Comment: the code inside get '/:id' loads everytime I open a page. Even if I load the just the main page.

Comment: does not matter if I browse http://localhost:8600/ or http://localhost:8600/345345, it always load. I do not want this to happen if I am just loading the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/:id' do
  #stuff
end

get '/' do
  #stuff
end

post '/' do
  #stuff
end
```

I believe posting the code in that order will take care of your priority. The way its routes is the order in which the method is written and the type of HTTP request (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line of text in my question. Please read it again.